# How load a page by using ajax process without history track?

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

In my website, i have no.of webpages, and i don't what to show the history (user should not use back button go shuffle between pages),

for that i am using this function:

html:

```
 <a class="challengeBtn changePage" data-link="task-1.html" href="#">Take the Hays Challenge</a>

 $('a.changePage').on('click',function(){
        var newPage = $(this).attr('data-link');
        $.mobile.loadPage(newPage);
    })
```

but page not at all loading from my local folder. any one help me to sort this?

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
```

to prevent jqm caching (history) when you start your application and then use

```
$.mobile.changePage(newPage);
```

to show the new page